# Are non-serialisable `Props` an anti-pattern?

Tags: akka

Example:

Suppose I have an actor that is managing communication with some external service, so it has a `Client` object within it for making requests to the external service. In order to avoid this actor becoming monolithic, I might want to create child actors for handling different pieces of interaction: maintaining a heartbeat to the service, making and coordinating complicated requests, etc. These child actors will need a reference to a `Client` of the service.

Given that these client objects are unlikely to be serialisable and may be stateful e.g. contain connection state, is it an anti pattern to pass them to child actors via `Props`? The Akka documentation seems to strongly encourage maintaining serialisable props, but this seems to be extremely limiting in this case.

Comment: To add to Yik's answer, yes it is pretty common. The only thing to watch out is trying to avoid mutate the object from children. If children just reads the objects, its fine. If the children requires to mutate it, you will have to take care of concurrency properly, which kinda defeats the ideology of Akka and one may argue its "anti pattern"

Comment: clients for external services tend to have some state in them like thread pools, connections etc. But these classes are naturally thread safe, and the "state" is not business logic state, it's just implementation details. So maybe it's OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Akka documentation seems to strongly encourage maintaining serialisable props

I am not aware of this suggestion, do you mind sharing the link in the question?

From my experience, it is pretty common to pass these `Client` references from parent to child actors. Sometimes I may choose to pass the exact method (a function) instead of the `Client` reference for the ease of unit testing. As long as you're not spawning an actor across the network boundary, I don't see any reason why this is a bad thing.

Regarding the `Client` object you describe, for network level things (e.g., connection state etc) I will leverage [akka-http Client API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html). If you were to keep application level things, I would prefer having a separate actor to be dedicated for such use. It sounds a bit anti-pattern to me to keep application state in non-actor provided that you have Akka actor, which is designed to host state.

Comment: I guess I was reading too much into the docs. Maybe they've changed over the years but the best I can do from the latest docs is the config flag for verifying all props are serialisable. Saying that, I can't find a single example in the docs where they pass something complicated and clearly non-serialisable into a Props. Thanks for the answer, probably seems like stating the obvious to you, but to me it fills a gap in the documentation and examples!

Comment: @tonicsoft Usually the example starts from simple, probably that's why. Anyway, glad it helps!